# How to return None in regex groups?

Tags: python, regex

How can I print out None in groups(), if the specific character is not found in the regex? First capture group should return None or 'S', but I'm having trouble returning None in print(t.groups()).

```
rx = r'^([S])([Nn]+)([m])([f]|[d])$'

t = re.match( rx , 'NNmf' )

print( t.groups() )
```

This is what I have tried so far, also using '?:' for not numbered capture group hoping it will return 'None' but no luck.

```
(None , ' NN ' , ' m ' , ' f ' )
```

Result should look above, currently I'm getting "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'".

Any suggestions will be much appreciated!

Comment: Like this your regex will not match your string. You might want to make the first group optional with a `?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"S" will have to be marked as an optional character. Since your search as anchored at the beginning, you should instead use `re.match`:

```
re.match('(S)?([Nn]+)(m)(f|d)$', 'NNmf').groups()
# (None, 'NN', 'm', 'f')
```

Comment: Sorry it was my misunderstanding, everything works perfectly. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What the answer means is that the `^` is implied if you use `match` instead of `search` so you don't need to specify it explicitly. You can still put it there if you want your regex to be longer for some reason.